# Transform a 3-column dataframe into a matrix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix

I have a dataframe df, for example:

```
A = [["John", "Sunday", 6], ["John", "Monday", 3], ["John", "Tuesday", 2], ["Mary", "Sunday", 6], ["Mary", "Monday", 4], ["Mary", "Tuesday", 7]] 
df = pandas.DataFrame(A, columns=["names", "dates", "times"])
```

And I want to reshape it so that, instead of three columns, I can create a matrix where the first column indexes the rows, the second column indexes the columns, and the third column becomes the matrix value, something like:

```
B = [["John", 6, 3, 2], ["Mary", 6, 4, 7]]
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(B, columns=["names", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday"])
```

or even better:

```
B = numpy.asarray(B)
B = pandas.DataFrame(B)
```

How do I transform A into B?

I have created a double for loop, but in my case df is very large and it takes a very long time. Is there a better way to do it?

This is not just a reshape, since A has 18 values and B has 8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table()`, e.g.:

```
In []:
df.pivot_table(columns='dates', index='names', values='times').reset_index()

Out[]:
dates names  Monday  Sunday  Tuesday
0      John       3       6        2
1      Mary       4       6        7
```

Comment: I'd add 'times' to eliminate that multiindex:  `df.pivot_table(index = 'names',columns = 'dates')['times'].reset_index()`

Comment: Good call, updated (used `values='times'` - instead of an index on the result).

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
df.set_index(['names','dates'])['times'].unstack().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
dates names  Monday  Sunday  Tuesday
0      John       3       6        2
1      Mary       4       6        7
```

Or:

```
pd.crosstab(df.names, df.dates, df.times, aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df.groupby(['names','dates']).sum()['times'].unstack().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df.pivot('names','dates','times').reset_index()
```

Comment: Some very quick timings showed the `set_index()` approach was the quickest on my machine.

Comment: Both great answers. I went with the other one just because I had to pick one and it was the first comment