# pandas pivot_table SQL equivalent

Tags: sql, pandas, postgresql, pivot, pivot-table

Can we in SQL (preferably Postgresql) mimic the pandas function [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)?

For example, let's say we have a table with the following 3 columns:

```
   Name        Day       Value
   John     Sunday           6
   John     Monday           3
   John     Tuesday          2
   Mary     Sunday           6
   Mary     Monday           4
   Mary     Tuesday          7
   Alex     Tuesday          1
```

I want to pivot the table so that the index is the name, the columns are the days, and cells are the values:

```
    names  Monday  Sunday  Tuesday
    John       3       6        2
    Mary       4       6        7
    Alex     null    null       1
```

*Part of the example was taken from the question* [Transform a 3-column dataframe into a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54048777/transform-a-3-column-dataframe-into-a-matrix)